# How to make EdgeWebView2 Authentication cookies persistence

Tags: microsoft-edge, webview2, edge-runtime

In our product we were using CEF browser for authentication and there we have two options
`persistent_session_cookies` and `persistent_user_preference` (keep sign in prompt option : yes or no) I always wanted to keep yes if user clicks on No also

Now we have replaced CEF to EdgeWebView2 and edgewebview2 I could not find any such option like that, every time I login to new authentication window it ask me to put credential.

I tried to check option in `ICoreWebView2EnviormentOptions` and `ICoreWebView2Settings` but could not find any such option to persistent cookies.

I need help here how we can achieve that ?

Comment: WebView2 doesn't have an option to persist session cookies. There is a `CoreWebView2.Profile.CookieManager` you might be able to use to manually persist session cookies by enumerating cookies looking for session cookies, serializing them, and then loading them back in the next time you create a WebView2. You can open a feature request on https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues.  What does persistent_user_preference do?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3444

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I am the only who added feature request on webview2 feedback page after david risney suggested in first comment

Comment: I know. I was linking to it for continuity.